# Infinite series with multiple variables

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I want to show that this infinite series converge to $3^{N}$ for all natural numbers N.
$\mathbb{Z}$ means integer.

$$\displaystyle \sum_{r_{k}∈\mathbb{Z}}  \frac{1}{2^{\sum_{k=1}^{N} |r_{k}|}} = \sum_{l=0}^{∞}\displaystyle \sum_{\sum_{k=1}^{N}|r_{k}|=l,r_{k} ∈\mathbb{Z}}  \frac{1}{2^{l}}$$

I tried to show it by induction but
I have no idea how to proceed at the induction step.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: How are you defining $r_k$? This is not listed, and $r_k$ could be any sequence of integers you want.

Answer (score -1):

A proof by induction is not the easiest way in that case; actually you only need to rearrange the terms, as well as the geometric series. Indeed, one has :
$$
\begin{array}{rrl}
S_N
   &:=& \displaystyle
   \sum_{r_1,\ldots,r_N\in\mathbb{Z}} 2^{-(|r_1|+\ldots+|r_N|)} \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   \sum_{r_1\in\mathbb{Z}} 2^{-|r_1|} \cdots \sum_{r_N\in\mathbb{Z}} 2^{-|r_N|} \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   \left(\sum_{r\in\mathbb{Z}} 2^{-|r|}\right)^N \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   \left(2\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} 2^{-n} - 1\right)^N \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   \left(\frac{2}{1-1/2}-1\right)^N \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   3^N
\end{array}
$$
*QED.*

Comment: Why the downvote ?